# Experiment with Autoshow method, Excel VBA, Value top 10, Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

saw this question was posted earlier but the answer was a workaround using a macro filter.  Still trying to understand how the "Autoshow Method" works from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835595.aspx

The code I'm working with is:

```
Sub Test()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot4").PivotFields("Base Contract #") _
 .AutoShow xlAutomatic, xlTop, 10, "Sum of Not Satisfactory"

End Sub
```

Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to get pivotTable properties of the worksheet class

What else do I need to declare to have the code work?

Thanks!
Art

Comment: Here's a similar question where `AutoShow` failed with the same error. Instead they used `.PivotFilters.Add2`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39136271/293078. They figured it out by using the Macro Recorder. Is that the question you were referring to?

Comment: Yes I saw that answer using the recorded macro which is fine but I'm curious about how to use the .Autoshow construction to do the same thing.

Comment: I looked around the web and saw one other person with the same question/1004 error, but there was no answer. I was thinking it might have to be a certain type of data source, but there's nothing to that effect in the MSDN help page you linked to.